# how to add a assembly from .net framework in the new csproj based dotnet core class libraries

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I cant figure out how i add a assembly from .net framework in the new csproj based dotnet core class libraries.

[image]

There used to be a framework tab in add reference.

Answer (score 2):

:I was able to add a reference to 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json' by editing directly the Project file (csproj) and add the following lines:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After adding it, I notice it was added inside NuGet packages, so I remove the lines, then go to NuGet administratior, select the 'Search' tab and type the assembly name, when it appears, I selected it an click 'Install'

[See how do I see the Nuget package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FImiE.png)

Have a great day!